# Command working fine but I get error whenever I dm the bot. [discord.py]

Tags: python, discord.py

so I have this code for my prefix. I have no problem with it. It's working fine, but whenever I message my bot it gives me this error. Is there anyway to ignore this or fix it? Thanks

```
with open("prefix.json") as f:
    prefixes = json.load(f)
    default_prefix = "?"

def prefix(client, message):
    id = message.guild.id
    return prefixes.get(id, default_prefix)

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix)

@client.command(name="Prefix", aliases=["prefix", "setprefix"])
@commands.has_permissions(manage_guild=True)
async def _prefix(ctx, new_prefix):
    msg = ctx.message
    prefixes[msg.guild.id] = new_prefix
    with open("prefix.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(prefixes, f, indent=4)

Error:
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 930, in on_message
    await self.process_commands(message)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 926, in process_commands
    ctx = await self.get_context(message)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 842, in get_context
    prefix = await self.get_prefix(message)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 787, in get_prefix
    ret = await discord.utils.maybe_coroutine(prefix, self, message)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\utils.py", line 317, in maybe_coroutine
    value = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/test.py", line 14, in prefix
    id = message.guild.id
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`message.guild` will be `None` for all DMs (as they aren't sent it a guild).  You should add a case for this in your `prefix` function.

```
def prefix(client, message):
    if not message.guild:
        return default_prefix
    id = message.guild.id
    return prefixes.get(id, default_prefix)
```